# Managed package Object not visible in my Profile>>Custom Object list

Tags: managed-package

I have a managed package object and want to include it as one of the tabs. Unfortunately, I am not able to find the object when I go to Profiles>> System Admin>> Custom Objects. I also tried visiting App Manager>>My Application >> Navigation Items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link helped me resolve :

https://www.levelupsalesforce.com/add-custom-object-tab-in-salesforce

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.